# amp-list src bound with embedded form will reset checked item

Tags: amp-html

Using a dummy form here I have a list of products where you have radio buttons to select quantity. When you select quantity 2 the very first time, I believe amp-bind kicks in and it reloads the amp-list and by doing so - the radio button that was checked is forgotten. But subsequent clicks after this - state is retained.

```
<amp-list id="paged-amp-list" layout="fixed-height" height="700" src="https://example.net/dev/puritan/amp1/products.php" [src]="'https://example.net/dev/puritan/amp1/products.php?page=' + pageNumber" single-item>
    ....
          <input type="radio" name="Quantity{{itemNumber}}" value="1" checked="checked" on="change:AMP.setState({quantity{{itemNumber}}: event.value})"> 1
          <input type="radio" name="Quantity{{itemNumber}}" value="2" on="change:AMP.setState({quantity{{itemNumber}}: event.value})"> 2
    ....
          <p [text]='quantity{{itemNumber}} + " Selected"'>1 Selected</p>
  </amp-list>

  <amp-state id="page" src="https://example.net/dev/puritan/amp1/products.php" [src]="'https://example.net/dev/puritan/amp1/products.php?page=' + pageNumber"></amp-state>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xYmEwy

Answer (score 1):

Looks like adding another binding to the radio button fixes it.

```
<input type="radio" name="Quantity{{itemNumber}}" [checked]='quantity{{itemNumber}} == 2' value="2" on="change:AMP.setState({quantity{{itemNumber}}: event.value})"> 2
```